# How to drop all empty tables in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I want to drop all tables that does not have rows.

How to drop all empty tables in SQLite?

**EDIT**
I need to do this on a mobile phone (no shell there). On a Windows Mobile phone.

Comment: Most likely can be done in shelling script or perl.

Comment: I need to do this on a mobile phone (no shell there). On a Windows Mobile phone.

Comment: We need to know what language(s) are available (cuz I'm not aware, anyway).

Comment: I can take what you told me, to put in c# for execution. But I am wondering if someone will answer later a way only with SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tables can be dropped, whether or not they have data in them when the command is executed.  Dunno of any database that operates otherwise.  So that means:

1) Getting a list of tables -

```
SELECT name 
  FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table'
```

2) Iterate over that list, using COUNT(*) to determine if any rows exist within a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM ~table
```

3) If the number returned is less than 1, execute a DROP statement:

```
DROP TABLE ~table
```

SQLite doesn't have function or stored procedure support - you'll have to do this from your application.

Comment: what's that ~ before table name stands for?

Comment: @Pentium10: psuedo variable.  If I used `$`, people might mistake it for a PHP variable.  `@` is MySQL & SQL Server syntax...

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over that list all within sqlite3?

Comment: @Horak: I can't find anything that suggests SQLite supports dynamic SQL on a quick googling.

Comment: @OMGPonies "select 1 from ~table limit 1" and checking if there are 0 or 1 rows returned might be faster, since you would need to iterate at most one row.