# Find the number of rows in each table in a large SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a large number of tables. I would like to find out which have zero rows (and drop them). I have not got very far! What I can do is list the tables using this SQL:

```sql
SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

Is there a way in SQLite of turning that into a loop and printing the COUNT(*) for each of the tables?

(N.B. I have looked at [Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), but I cannot see how they might help.)

Comment: You can find the table names via the `sqlite_master` table like so, and loop over them in your programming language of choice to get the count of each table in turn.

Comment: I'm interested in doing it in SQL statements on SQLite, is that possible?

Comment: Nope. Not possible in just sql.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300080/how-to-drop-all-empty-tables-in-sqlite

Comment: Thanks @QSOFT, sadly it's the bits done in English in that answer I wanted code for. I'm taking Shawn's advice and doing it in code (Python)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way in SQLite of turning that into a loop and printing the COUNT(*) for each of the tables?

Thanks to the magic of sqlite3, the answer is yes if we allow that sqlite3 is part of SQLite.

Anyway, the technique comes in very handy.

Assuming $db is the database file of interest:

```
echo "SELECT 'SELECT count(*), \"' || name || '\" FROM ' || name || ';'  FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';" |
    sqlite3 -readonly "$db" | sqlite3 -readonly "$db"
```

For the famous flights.db database, this produces:

```
8107|airports
6048|airlines
67663|routes
1|sqlite_stat1
24|sqlite_stat4
```

Season to taste.

Comment: Nice one dude! ;)

Answer (score 4):

First number in stat column of sqlite_stat1 is the number of rows. So, if you have write privileges, then:

```
ANALYZE main;
select * from sqlite_stat1
```

If the database is never changing in size, you can just run the second command any time after running ANALYZE just once. But you'll have to rerun ANALYZE if the database is frequently changed.